# Solving a matrix differential equation by using a function that takes a matrix as its argument

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, parametric-functions

I have a function `g` of the form

```
g[y_]:=A.y.B
```

where `y` is a 2-by-2 matrix whose elements are in turn functions of time `t`.

I am trying to solve an equation that consists of a differential equation of the following form:

```
D[y,t]==g[y]
```

with the initial condition `y[0]=={{a,b},{c,d}}`.

If I use the command

```
NDSolve[D[y,t]==g[y],y[0]=={{a,b},{c,d}},y,{t,t1,t2}]
```

where the parameters have been defined previously, then I get the error message saying that `y[0]` cannot be used as a function. I would be grateful for any suggestions regarding how to handle this problem and generate the solution as a time-dependent 2-by-2 matrix.

Comment: The only way I know to do this is to define a function for each component of `y` so that it becomes `{{y11[t],y12[t]},{y21[t],y22[t]}}`

Comment: Mikado’s suggestion seems to be the go-to solution. I’d also like to note that OP is using `NDSolve` with seemingly only symbolic parameters defined, and may run into such issues after mikado’s suggestion is applied.

Comment: note also that you have some syntax errors: `y` is being used as a variable in `D[y,t]==g[y]` as opposed to `D[y[t], t] == g[y[t]]`, and you're giving your conditions as multiple arguments instead of as a single list, i.e. it needs to be `{D[y,t]==g[y], y[0]=={{a,b},{c,d}}}`

Comment: giving numerical values to things, e.g. `A = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]; B = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]; {{a, b}, {c, d}} = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]; t1 = 0; t2 = 1;`,  then `NDSolve[{D[y[t], t] == g[y[t]], y[0] == {{a, b}, {c, d}}}, y, {t, t1, t2}]` works; you don't need to define each component individually.

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, and thank you all for your comments. I have recently succeeded in getting my code to work by evolving each element of the matrix separately (as mentioned by mikado), although I feel it would be better to have a provision in Mathematica about this, which would make the commands much shorter and transparent. I had tried thorimur's method earlier, but for some reason it was not working, probably because it was the part of a larger code and this part was not compatible with the earlier commands.